# Meteor.call() inside a polymer-element causes error

Tags: javascript, meteor, polymer

currently i am working MeteorJS with polymer 0.5, when i write Meteor.call() (MeteorJS function used to send data to server) inside an polymer-element cause an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

my code is

```
signUpTap: function(event, detail, sender) {
    var _this = this;

    Meteor.call("signUp", function(_this.signUp, response) {
        _this.toastOpened = false;

        if (error) {
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                _this.toastText = error.reason;
                _this.toastOpened = true;
            }, 400);
        } else {
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                _this.toastText = response;
                _this.toastOpened = true;
            }, 400);
        }
    });
}
```

i think it's due to clash between Meteor.call() & polymer call() functions how i avoid this ?

Comment: A conflict between the two call functions is unlikely. The error you posted often occurs when HTML is treated as JS. What happens when you comment out both `_this.toastText =`.. ?

Comment: signUpTap: function(event, detail, sender) {
            Meteor.call("signUp", function({}, response) {
            });
        }, also gives same error

Comment: So the error is triggered server-side?

Comment: i cant execute the tap code above becoz polymer-elemnt view not visible, that means no code execution @ server

Comment: So where does the console say, the error is cause excactly?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Meteor.call()` calls a server-side method. The first argument is the method name (in this case "signUp"). You seem to have arguments which should be part of the method call as arguments in your callback function.
http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_call

I think you want something like `Meteor.call("signUp", _this.signUp, function(error, response)`